# HTML image formatting

Tags: html, image

How can I clip an image according to the screen resolution like on `www.webworks.0fees.net`. My page needs to be scrolled way to the right. Can I just clip it to the right size so that it automatically gets adjusted to the correct size according to any screen resolution?

Comment: i've just used an image which is just right for my screen resolution.But when viewd with different resolutions, the page needs to be scrolled a lot. So i wanted to know if i could prevent this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic approaches:

- Set it as a background image
- Apply `overflow: hidden` to your body element

Comment: umm,but then a lot of content gets hidden for lower scren resolutions. Anyways thanks . Also, my problem is that ,if i use a background image, i can't animate my buttons,any advice with that ?

Comment: @Anant You could try using media queries to use a different image for lower resolutions: http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/hardboiled_css3_media_queries